# Are PMOS still ideal for Reverse voltage protection of 75 A

Tags: high-current, pmos, reverse-polarity

I am creating a power management circuit for a 20m RGBW led strip, these leds operate on 5v and would require a current consumption of about 60A. I will actually split it into 8 channels of 2or3 meters so that it wont be hard handling all that current.

Ill be using one of those [5v 350W](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000742784462.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.2aa63c00oTA9B1&mp=1) powersupply. When connecting the power supply to my circuit i would like to *"idiot proof"* myself and prevent me from connecting the + and - backwards. The way i have always done it is using a PMOS configuration such as this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnfBn3m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Its very simple, and only use 1 component thus cheap to implement since i will only be making 3 of these. I did find this PMOS that says the package limit is 60A [CSD25404Q3](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/Texas-Instruments-TI-CSD25404Q3T_C202154.pdf) so if i place a heatsink on it its possible to push for 100A. there is also this slightly more expensive [SUM110P04-05](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/Vishay-Intertech-SUM110P04-05-E3_C75084.pdf) which i think would not require anymore heatsink.

So for my concerns:

1. Will this circuit work for me theoretically?
2. what are the things i should look out for? I have my eyes on thermals and do have questions that needs to be answered, but that would be for another thread, I would like to focus about the circuit and parts used on this one

Comment: "I will actually split it into 8 channels..." - can you just put one 9530 on each channel?

Comment: @ErikR im actually dumbfounded that i did not think of that. I think that would be a better approach instead of 1 very powerful fet, have 8 lesser fets instead.

Comment: Maybe even simpler: can't the LEDs block 5V by themselves ? Or is there also some kind of logic in the LED strip?

Comment: That PMOS configuration won't block current, it will turn on in both directions.

Comment: @Aaron the backwards mosfet reverse polarity protection circuit is well-known. Sounds to me like the OP has used it before and understands how to use it correctly. Maybe search on that term (backwards mosfet reverse polarity protection).

Comment: @tobalt most LED's have a low reverse voltage rating. Some white LED's I have seen seem to have almost no reverse blocking ability. I think they may actually have ordinary silicon diodes in anti-parallel configuration to protect against reverse voltage.

Answer (score 1):

The single PMOS configuration with the gate connected to ground will allow current to flow in either direction.  *It's always on.*

You want something more akin to the below. A few more components, but absolutely prevents current flow in the reverse direction.

[image]

<del>Though I think that the better option is to split it up like mentioned in the comments, and use a simpler Schottkey diode for each string.</del>

**EDIT:**
I was thinking of regular diode action, meaning, preventing current flow from going right to left in your circuit diagram.
**BUT** Your post is about reverse polarity input power.  And yes, your single transistor P-FET circuit will work to protect against that.